# SQL subquery with COUNT help

Tags: sql

I have an SQL statement that works

```
SELECT * FROM eventsTable WHERE columnName='Business'
```

I want to add this as a subquery...

```
COUNT(Business) AS row_count
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This is probably the easiest way, not the prettiest though:

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM eventsTable WHERE columnName = 'Business') as RowCount
    FROM eventsTable
    WHERE columnName = 'Business'
```

This will also work without having to use a `group by`

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () as RowCount
    FROM eventsTables
    WHERE columnName = 'Business'
```

Comment: Please note that `OVER` is not supported by the SQL standard, and it won't be available across all the RDBMS (For example, [MySQL doesn't support it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292679/mysql-using-correct-syntax-for-the-over-clause)).

Answer (score 22):

```
SELECT e.*,
       cnt.colCount 
FROM eventsTable e
INNER JOIN (
           select columnName,count(columnName) as colCount
           from eventsTable e2 
          group by columnName
           ) as cnt on cnt.columnName = e.columnName
WHERE e.columnName='Business'
```

-- Added space

Answer (score 10):

Do you want to get the number of rows?

```
SELECT columnName, COUNT(*) AS row_count
FROM eventsTable
WHERE columnName = 'Business'
GROUP BY columnName
```

Comment: Can't have `where` clause in group by. Use `Having`

Comment: @Jim - You can use have a `where` clause with `group by`.  You would need to use `having` if you wanted to filter on the result of an aggregate when using `group by`.

Comment: The Where clause would need to be before Group By and the Having would need to be after the Group By.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a column named business:

`SELECT Business, COUNT(*) FROM eventsTable GROUP BY Business`