# MySql using correct syntax for the over clause

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

What is the correct syntax to get the over clause to work in mysql?

I would like to see the total sms's sent by each user without grouping it with the group by clause.

```
SELECT 
    username, 
    count(sentSmsId) OVER (userId) 
FROM 
    sentSmsTable,
    userTable
WHERE
    userId = sentUserId;
```

Comment: what kind of result do you want to have through this query?

Comment: I would like to see the total sms's sent by each user without grouping it with the group by clause.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no OVER clause in MySQL that I know of, but here is a link that might assist you to accomplish the same results:

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is no longer true for MySQL 8: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Answer (score 20):

MySQL 8 has got the [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)! Therefore, you can write your query in it like this:

```
SELECT username, 
       count(sentSmsId) OVER (partition by userId) 
FROM sentSmsTable
JOIN userTable ON userId = sentUserId;
```

Answer (score 5):

MySQL does not currently support window functions, so `over()` will only yield syntax errors (or garbage, if it's accepted regardless).

Answer (score 3):

MySQL Doesn't have window functions until the most recent release: MySQL 8 (release in April, 2018). MS SQL Server also accepts OVER clause.

The syntax is:

```
function(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3)
```

Check out https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/ for more examples.