# Calculate percentage and total after create categories mysql

Tags: mysql

I've this query

```
SELECT 
    trage,
    CASE trage 
        WHEN '<18' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE <18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN '18-24' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 18 AND AGE <= 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN '25-34' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 34 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN '35-44' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 35 AND AGE <= 44 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN '45-54' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 45 AND AGE <= 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN '>=55' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 55 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    END Total
FROM 
(   SELECT 
        t_personne.pers_date_naissance, 
        t_personne.pers_date_inscription, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        - CASE 
            WHEN MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
             OR (MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) = MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
             AND DAY(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > DAY(t_personne.pers_date_inscription))
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 
          END AS AGE
    FROM t_personne
) AS Total
CROSS JOIN
(   SELECT '<18' trage UNION ALL
    SELECT '18-24' UNION ALL
    SELECT '25-34' UNION ALL
    SELECT '35-44' UNION ALL
    SELECT '45-54' UNION ALL
    SELECT '>=55'
)a
GROUP BY trage
ORDER BY FIELD(trage, '<18', '18-24', '25-34', '35-44', '45-54', '>=55')
```

it give a table with two columns trage and Total for all categories

How to add a column percentage with a line TOTAL for the column Total and %

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, you can't do this. To support this MySQL needs Window Function support which it still doesn't have. If you need functions like these I would recommend switching to PostgreSQL.

Also take a look at this question: [MySql using correct syntax for the over clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292679/mysql-using-correct-syntax-for-the-over-clause)

Comment: Thanks but why I've a -2 for reputation it's just a question ? And I don't understand why it's an over clause ?

Comment: Not sure why people downvoted your question, it's a clear and simple well formatted. Although the examples you had previously were even more helpful :) As for the over clause, that's the syntax for Window functions in SQL. Here's how you would do it in PostgreSQL for example: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: That's life but thank you for enlightening me :) I am a self-taught amateur. I have an external server with phpmyadmin and mysql so I'll see the track you suggest me.

Comment: +1 from me anyhow. It's a good question which many people have :)