# Mysql server syntax error

Tags: mysql

I get syntax error using MySQL on the following sql statement:

```
Select * from 
(

Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY td asc) rn  FROM emp 

),cte2 AS ( 
SELECT c2.*, CASE WHEN c.req_type != c2.req_type THEN 'Req changed from'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,c2.req_type)+' to '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,c.req_type)     ELSE '' END AS reqc, 
CASE WHEN c.token != c2.token THEN 'Token changed from' +CONVERT(VARCHAR,c2.token)+' to '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,c.token) ELSE '' END AS tokenc
 FROM cte c INNER join cte c2 ON c2.rn+1 = c.rn
 )
```

Can someone tell what is wrong here ? I get Error Code:

> 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax;   check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version  for the right syntax to use
> near '(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY td asc) rn  FROM emp) as cte, (

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql using correct syntax for the over clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292679/mysql-using-correct-syntax-for-the-over-clause)

Comment: What does the first `Select * from ` stand for?

Comment: MySQL does not support window functions or common table expressions or `+` for string concatenation.  Your query looks like SQL Server syntax.  Perhaps you should run it in that database.