# Can anybody tell what's wrong in this mysql code?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    unix_timestamp, 
    LAG(unix_timestamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY unix_timestamp) 
    As Previous_time
FROM mydb.query_one
LIMIT 5;
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY unix_timestamp) AS previous_time,              RO' at line 5
> 0.056 sec

Comment: what is the mysql version?

Comment: I don't think this is MySQL Syntax (OVER statement does not exist in MySQL, only sql-server, postgre...)
similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292679/mysql-using-correct-syntax-for-the-over-clause
Edit : you need MySQL 8 or above

Comment: Have you checked whether your MySQL support `OVER` or not????  That's probably the first thing you should check before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL only supports window functions starting with version 8.0.  Instead, you can do:

```
SELECT qo.user_id, qo.unix_timestamp, 
       (SELECT MAX(qo2.unix_timestamp) 
        FROM mydb.query_one qo2
        WHERE qo2.user_id = qo.user_id AND qo2.unix_timestamp < qo.unix_timestamp
       ) as Previous_time
FROM mydb.query_one
LIMIT 5;
```

For performance you want an index on `(user_id, unix_timestamp)`.

Comment: Yea, you are right, Window function is not gonna work for the version I'm using. Thanks.

Comment: Is there no better way? This seems like it would be super slow.

Comment: @BenFarmer . . . An appropriate index should speed it up.  But by now, almost everyone should be using MySQL 8+.