# workaround for OVER() in Mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql

I am trying to migrate my existing data from oracle to mysql and am having a constraint of going with Mysql5.6. I have one view in the DB which is using OVER() clause. When I am trying to run the CREATE query in mysql workbench, it straight away gives me a syntex error around OVER().

Can someone please help me with a workaround.

Part of the DDL

```
COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY mei.ID ORDER BY mei.EVENTDATE ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) COUNT,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY mei.ID,mei.SUBTRANTYPEVIEW ORDER BY mei.EVENTDATE ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

Comment: Please do not tag `[mysql]` questions with `[oracle]`. They are two different RDBMS products (even if owned by the same corporation).

Comment: MySQL 5.6 does not supports window functions. It was added to MySQL 8.

Comment: You have to use user defined variables for that, but they don't work in a view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql using correct syntax for the over clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292679/mysql-using-correct-syntax-for-the-over-clause)

Answer (score 0):

the syntax between oracle db and mysql is a little different

Example: 
SELECT a, b,
        COUNT(*) OVER()
             FROM table

is equivalent to: 
SELECT a, b,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table )
             FROM table