# Lag() function not working in mysql workbench 8.0

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

```
SELECT created_at, grand_total, 
lag(grand_total,1) over (order by o.grand_total desc) as 'lag'
FROM sales_flat_order;
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '(order by o.grand_total desc) as 'lag'       FROM
> sales_flat_order' at line 2   0.016 sec

code fails at: over **(**order by o.grand_total desc)

Comment: What version of mysql (not workbench) are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Check which MySQL version are you using

[Simulate lag function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql)

[MySql using correct syntax for the over clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292679/mysql-using-correct-syntax-for-the-over-clause)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT created_at, grand_total, 
       (select grand_total
        from sales_flat_order sfo2
        where sfo2.grand_total > sfo.grand_total
        order by sfo2.grand_total asc
        limit 1
       )
FROM sales_flat_order sfo;
```

Note that `lag()` with a descending sort is more commonly called "lead".