# Loop over result in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

How is it possible to loop over a set of selected results in a stored procedure and take out the ones that match a criteria.

If it shouldn't need a loop or something of the sort how would I achieve this?

So lets say we have a select statement like so

```sql
SELECT DefaultID, Weight, Length, Height, Width FROM tblDefault 
WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID AND  DeleteDateUTC is null
```

But how can I get only the rows that also match the criteria

```sql
IF SELECT 1 FROM tblOther WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID AND CustomerUserID=CustomerUserID 
AND DefaultID=@DefaultID returns 1 row 

OR SELECT 1 FROM tblOther WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID AND DefaultID=@DefaultID returns nothing
```

In short I am wanting to select rows in `tblDefault` where the `defaultID` is in `tblOther` with the `CustomerUserID` **or** the `defaultID` isn't in `tblOther`

Comment: You rarely need to loop with SQL. Some whizz will come along with the correct proc, but the direction will probably be to use [group by with count()](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-group-by.php), and use that either in a join or as a subquery with the first statement you have.

Comment: Check the second paragraph :P. I didn't think it would need one and there would be some smart way of doing it.

Comment: I've no idea what you're referring to.

Comment: "If it shouldn't need a loop or something of the sort how would I achieve this?"

Comment: Ah, *your* second paragraph :) Oh well, then I was just backing you up!

Comment: Thanks. :). Maybe some subselects will help. But how can I check the amount of rows returned?

Comment: Remembering that we need to use the defaultID returned from the initial query

Comment: [Using info from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884733/sql-subquery-with-count-help) I get `SELECT DefaultID WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID AND CustomerUserID=CustomerUserID 
AND DefaultID=@DefaultID
HAVING count(*) > 0` as your subselect/join. Something like that.

Comment: But how can I use defaultID in the subquery when I am getting it in the main query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question check [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) (if I correctly understood your question - otherwise please edit your question to make more sense)

```
SELECT d.DefaultID, d.Weight, d.Length, d.Height, d.Width 
FROM tblDefault d
WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID AND  DeleteDateUTC is null
AND (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblOther WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID AND CustomerUserID=@CustomerUserID 
     AND DefaultID=d.DefaultID) 
OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblOther WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID AND DefaultID=d.DefaultID))
```

Comment: Check the edit. Last line. I think I may have cleared up what I wanted.

Comment: @cha good idea, no need for count as exists will work for both cases, +1

Comment: But `DefaultID` is not a passed parameter, it is one of the columns we select in the main query.

Comment: Or do I just not understand sql? xD. Which is more likely the case

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the query that meets your conditions:

```
SELECT DefaultID, Weight, Length, Height, Width
FROM tblDefault td
WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID AND  DeleteDateUTC is null and
     ( (SELECT count(*)
        FROM tblOther t
        WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID AND t.CustomerUserID=td.CustomerUserID AND DefaultID=@DefaultID
       ) = 1 or
       not exists (SELECT 1 FROM tblOther WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID AND DefaultID=@DefaultID)
    )
```